# how to call a lambda of unknown type

Tags: java

Consider we have a set of variables containing references to methods:

```
public double m2(String s, int n){return n;}
Runnable r = ()->{};
Consumer<String> c1 = System.out::println;
BiFunction<String, Integer, Double> f2 = this::m2;
```

We can call them in different ways, depending on concrete variable type:

```
    r.run();
    c1.accept("Hello");
    Object res = f2.apply("Hello", 1);
```

Now, I need a global method to invoke any type of referenced methods:

```
public static Object call(Object lambda, Object... args) {...}
Object res0 = call(r); // returns null
Object res1 = call(c1, "Hello");
Object res2 = call(f2, "Hello", 1)
```

How to implement this method? The set of possible functional types of the parameter `lambda` is not limited.

Comment: There is already an implementation of this method.  It is called [Method#invoke(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-).  You can `getParameterCount()`, `getParameterTypes()`, and `getReturnType()` to determine how to call this “lambda”.

Comment: Do you expect an answer other than straightforward reflection?

Comment: Maybe the **java scripting API** would be a better tool: one can set variables in the scripting engine and such.

Comment: @AJNeufeld in order to use `Method#invoke(...)`, we need to extract method from lambda. Naive attempt `Method m = (Method)r;` results in `exceptionjava.lang.ClassCastException: org.df4j.reflect.FindActionTest$$Lambda$1/445884362 cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.Method`

Comment: @LouisWasserman  straightforward reflection would be good.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov Yes, I posted it as a comment, not an answer.  It was meant as a hint to get you looking in the right direction. Work was still needed to extract from the lambda (which is an object, of a class), the required `Method`.  Both Max & Sarel have demonstrated the required steps in their answers.

Answer (score 5):

You need to identify the type of the object and call/invoke it appropriately. The following method checks for `Runnable`, `Callable`, `Method` and anything that is annotated with `FunctionalInterface`. If the type is `Method` it will assume that the first parameter is the object on which to invoke the method on.

```
public Object callWhatever(final Object o, final Object... params) throws Exception
{
    if (o instanceof Runnable) {
        ((Runnable)o).run();
        return null;
    }

    if (o instanceof Callable) {
        return ((Callable<?>)o).call();
    }

    if (o instanceof Method) {
        return ((Method)o).invoke(params[0], Arrays.copyOfRange(params, 1, params.length));
    }

    final Method method = getMethodForFunctionalInterface(o);
    if (method != null) {
        return method.invoke(o, params);
    }

    throw new InvalidParameterException("Object of type " + o.getClass() +  " is not callable!");
}
```

The method `getMethodForFunctionalInterface` uses reflection to walk through the passed object's classes and interfaces, looking for a `FunctionalInterface` annotation. This annotation is present on all Java8 functionals, lambdas etc.  It will then look for the method that needs to be invoked and return it (functional interfaces are allowed to have only one public abstract method, so it's easy to find it):

```
public Method getMethodForFunctionalInterface(final Object o) {
    Class<?> clazz = o.getClass();
    while (clazz != null) {
        for (final Class<?> interfaze : clazz.getInterfaces()) {
            if (interfaze.isAnnotationPresent(FunctionalInterface.class)) {
                for (final Method method : interfaze.getDeclaredMethods()) {
                    if (Modifier.isAbstract(method.getModifiers())) {
                        return method;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
    }
    return null;
}
```

*Please note that custom functional interfaces without the `FunctionalInterface` annotation are allowed by Java and will **not** be detected by this method.*

Now you can call whatever:

```
public void test() throws Exception {
    final Runnable runnable = ()->{System.out.println("r called");};
    final Callable<Integer> callable = ()->{System.out.println("c called"); return 123456; };
    final Consumer<String> consumer = System.out::println;
    final BiFunction<String, Integer, Double> bifunction = this::m2;

    final Object test1 = callWhatever(runnable);
    final Object test2 = callWhatever(callable);
    final Object test3 = callWhatever(consumer, "Hello World");
    final Object test4 = callWhatever(bifunction, "Hello", 123);
    final Object test5 = callWhatever(this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("m2", String.class, int.class), this, "Hello", 234);

    System.out.println(test1);
    System.out.println(test2);
    System.out.println(test3);
    System.out.println(test4);
    System.out.println(test5);
}
```

Output:

> r called
>   c called
>   Hello World
>   null
>   123456
>   null
>   123.0
>   234.0

Comment: from java doc:
* However, the compiler will treat any interface meeting the
 definition of a functional interface as a functional interface
  regardless of whether or not a {@code FunctionalInterface}
  annotation is present on the interface declaration.*
maybe you just need to check if there only one public abstract method

Comment: @SarelFoyerlicht Good point, I have clarified my answer that this will **not** work for custom interfaces without the annotation.

Comment: if we follow the rule of functional interfaces are allowed to have only one public abstract method

Comment: public static Object call(Object object, Object... param) throws Exception {
        Method method = null;
        int publicMethods=0;
        for (Method m:object.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
            if(Modifier.isPublic(m.getModifiers())&&!m.isDefault()){
                method=m;
                publicMethods++;
            }
        }

        if(publicMethods==1){
            Object returnValue = method.invoke(object, param);
            return returnValue;
        }
 throw new InvalidParameterException("Object of type"+ object.getClass()+" is not callable!"); }

Answer (score 3):

NOTE: this answer is based on [Max Vollmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9199167/max-vollmer) answer, but it has a different approach.

In java, Lambda expression is defined by

> @FunctionalInterface

that has the rule of

> functional interface has exactly one abstract method.

so we can check if our Object is following that rule and then call that one method

```
public class Example {

public Example() throws Exception {
    final Runnable runnable = ()->{System.out.println("r called");};
    final Callable<Integer> callable = ()->{System.out.println("c called"); return 1000; };
    final Consumer<String> consumer = System.out::println;
    final BiFunction<String, Integer, Double> bifunction = this::m2;
    final InterfaceWithDefault inter =()->{System.out.println("print");};

    final Object test1 = call(runnable);
    final Object test2 = call(callable);
    final Object test3 = call(consumer, "Hello World");
    final Object test4 = call(bifunction, "Hello", 123);
    final Object test5 = call(inter);

    System.out.println(test1);
    System.out.println(test2);
    System.out.println(test3);
    System.out.println(test4);
    System.out.println(test5);
}
public static Object call(Object object, Object... param) throws Exception {
    Method method = null; 
    int publicMethods=0; 
    for (Method m:object.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) { 
        if(Modifier.isPublic(m.getModifiers())&&!m.isDefault()){ 
          method=m; 
          publicMethods++; 
         } 
    } 
    if(publicMethods==1)
    { 
        Object returnValue = method.invoke(object, param); 
        return returnValue; 
    } 
    throw new InvalidParameterException("Object of type"+ object.getClass()+" is not callable!"); 
}
public double m2(String s, int n){return n;}
public interface InterfaceWithDefault{
    public void print();
    default void defaultBar() {System.out.println("x");}
}
}
```

Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Example exa = new Example();
    }
}
```

and the output:

```
r called
c called
Hello World
print
null
1000
null
123.0
null
```

Note1: we don't need to check if abstract because of our object already overwrite it, but there can't be more than 1 public methods unless the others are a default(no case I was able to think about)
Note2: it can run also classes with only 1 public method

Answer (score 2):

"Lambda expression" is not a type of value (like "object" or "int"). It is a way of expressing a value, like a string literal.

In Java, you cannot write "a method that takes a string literal" - you can only write a method that takes a string. You have no way of telling if the argument was created using a literal or not.

It's exactly the same with lambdas - you cannot write a method that "takes a lambda" or treats lambdas as some special case. Once you use a lambda to create an instance of an interface, it's lambda-specific properties are gone, at least from the point of view of the Java semantics.

In short, what you try to achieve is not a sound use of lambdas - you will wither need reflection, or rethinking of your architecture.

**-- edit: two points to clarify**

1. It's exactly the same with inner classes - when you have a reference to an object implementing *SomeInterface*, there is no way of knowing if it was implemented with an inner class or a top-level class. There is no "inner class value type".
2. Note that lambda can be used to construct a value of any interface - you can have an interface with any number of methods, then have it extended with another interface, with default implementation for all but one method, and then define the last one with a lambda.

(edited again, thanks to Sarel Foyerlicht for pointing out a mistake)

Comment: by "lambda" I mean any value which can be obtained by one of the above mentioned ways: lambda expression or method reference.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov: and that is exactly where you miss the point. There is no "lambda value" in Java, there are just plain objects implementing interfaces or inheriting classes.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov: I think that the main point here is that you try to treat lambda as a part of your library API  (as in: "people pass lambdas to the library") - which is impossible due to what "lambdas" are in Java. In Java, your interface must always be "people pass instances of interfaces to the library".

Comment: about 2, I try to do that, but you can't make an object with 'AbstractClass abstractClass =()->{System.out.println("x");};' I got an error. you can have an object inside the abstract class that holds lambda but that not make hole the class a lambda... (my other classes "public interface Inter {
    public void m1();
    public void m2();
    public void m3();
}
", "public abstract  class AbstractClass implements Inter{
    public void m2(){};
    public void m3(){};
}
")

Comment: @SarelFoyerlicht - my bad about the abstract class - of course the target of lambda conversion must be an interface. But the point remains true - it's enough to replace the abstract class with an interface with default methods, and you can have an instance of an interface with any number of methods - instantiated with a lambda (I will edit my post)